# bash for with numerical comparison and file existence

Tags: bash, for-loop, file-io, multiple-conditions

I tried to do a for loop with 2 conditions but I didn't succeed in any way:

```
for (( i=0 ; -e /file && i < 10 ; i++ ))
```

of course I tried any combination of parentheses like:

```
for (( i=0 ; [ -e /file ] && [ i < 10 ] ; i++ ))

for (( i=0 ; [ -e /file -a i < 10 ] ; i++ ))
```

What's wrong on this?
I googled a lot for this, but I didn't find any suggestion.

Comment: Good first question, but you should include the error message you get in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do some subshell trickery to pull this off:

```
for (( i=0 ; $([ -e /file -a $i -lt 10 ]; echo "$?") == 0; i++ ))
```

Or probably better:

```
for (( i=0 ; $([ -e /file ]; echo "$?") == 0 && i < 10; i++ ))
```

What's happening here is that `$(...)` is being run and placed into the mathematical expression `... == 0`. When it's run the `echo "$?"` spits out the return code for `[` which is 0 for no-error (i.e. expression is true), and 1 for error (i.e. expression is false) which then gets inserted as `0 == 0` or `1 == 0`.